# Measure startup times of tmux

Tags: tmux, performance, tmux-plugin-manager

I'd like to profile the performance of `tmux`. In particular how fast starting up a session is (and maybe also attaching to a session). I'm especially interested in how the content of my `.tmux.conf` file affects startup times (I use plugins).

How could I measure that in an objective way?

As an example of what I'm interested in, I run this to profile the startup times of my `zsh` setup.

```bash
repeat 5 {/usr/bin/time zsh -i -c exit}
```

I've tried automating things with commands like the one below, but I can't figure out how to get timings. Also, this seems to execute asynchonously, the command finishes before the session is killed.

```bash
tmux new-session -d -s test && tmux send-keys "exit" Enter
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for startup time:

```
date +%T.%N; tmux -Ltest new -d 'date +%T.%N; sleep 10'
tmux -Ltest capturep -p|sed '/^$/d'
tmux -Ltest kill-server
```

You can also add -vv to tmux and you will get a log file with timestamps, but it will take some interpretation...

Comment: I can't manage to capture anything. `tmux -L test capturep -p` doesn't output anything but empty lines

Comment: It works for me, maybe your date doesn't work or doesn't have %N. What if you do "new -d 'echo xyz; sleep 10'"?

Comment: Just empty lines

Comment: Strange, if you attach you don't see anything either? Even if you scroll into the history with C-b [?

Comment: If I attach I see the output in the pane.